# Parsing csv with javascript or d3js: how to skip a column?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I have two versions of a horizontal bar chart, stacked and paired (aka grouped).  The code for each is stuffed into their own functions.

Refer to lines 35-43 `(var stacked = function (){ ... })` and lines 117-121 `(var paired = function (){ ... })` to see how the CSV is currently being parsed: http://tributary.io/inlet/8832116

Uncomment line 197 and below to see the stacked version rendered.  To do this I manually changed the data, not ideal.

**GOAL:** I want to parse the csv file and drop a column programmatically, rather than remove it manually and save 2 separate csv files.

I need to parse the csv and remove this with native d3 or javascript code, but how?

Shown in code.

I have:

```
Category,Total,Under $1000, ...
Music,14744,1434, ...
Art,12796,1216, ...
```

I need total removed:

```
Category,Under $1000, ...
Music,1434, ...
Art,1216, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the CSV string in memory (a variable string), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `\n` to get the lines, loop over each line and split on `,`. This will give you an array of the column values for a given line.

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) out the column you don't want, and then join line back with `,` - this will get you back a line of CSV data that you can [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) onto a `result` array.

Finally at the end, join the `result` array with `\n` and there you have it - a new string containing CSV data without column you don't want.

Note that this will not properly handle quotes / other gotcha's that come with CSV data, but if your data doesn't contain any of that you're in the clear.

---

Sample using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
// raw CSV data from somewhere
var csv = 
'Category,Total,Under $1000\n' +
'Music,14744,1434,3450\n' +
'Art,12796,1216,7748\n';

// split on newlines, map over each line
var newCsv = csv.split('\n').map(function(line) {
    var columns = line.split(','); // get the columns
    columns.splice(1, 1); // remove total column
    return columns;
}).join('\n'); // join on newlines

console.log(newCsv);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PZ9vM/

Answer (score 1):

Add the column removal as suggested by Trevor to [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm) and your csv parser can handle stuff like quotes as well.

Comment: +1. There are so many pre-existing CSV solutions. If it was TSV data there aren't as much things to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just use some splicing and slicing?

```
var data;    //note, you're loading it in as a flat file with $.get()
$.get("/url/to/the/csvfile", function(d){
    data = d.splice("\n");
    var length = data.length; //so as to save loop runtime
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        data[i] = data[i].splice(",")[0] + data[i].splice(",").slice(2)
        //this will split data[i] into the first piece before the comma
        //along with everything from the 2nd index to the end of the
        //array that was spliced with ","            
    }
}
```

splicing and slicing are so much fun...

**edit:**
I forgot that you don't need to specify the end index with `.slice()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nifty little vanilla JavaScript for you to remove a column from CSV data:

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Dj9/2/)

**Code:**

```
var csv = 
'Category,Total,Under $1000\n' +
'Music,14744,1434,3450\n' +
'Art,12796,1216,7748\n';

// Made it a function to make it reusable!
function removeColumn(data, colIndex) {
    var temp = data.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
        temp[i] = temp[i].split(",");
        temp[i].splice(colIndex,1);
        temp[i] = temp[i].join(","); // comment this if you want a 2D array
    }
    return temp.join("\n");     // returns CSV
    return temp;                // returns 2D array
    return d3.csv.parse(temp);  // returns a parsed object
}

console.log(removeColumn(csv,1));
```